# I can't start this file which i downloaded for an academic project, show missing method error

Tags: java, spring-boot, pom.xml

This file came with missing dependencies and now i'm stuck. What am i missing?

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/Claudio/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback- 
classic/1.2.3/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/Claudio/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j- 
log4j12/1.6.6/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.6.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
SLF4J: The requested version 1.7.16 by your slf4j binding is not compatible with [1.6]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#version_mismatch for further details.

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
[32m :: Spring Boot :: [39m      [2m (v2.3.2.RELEASE)[0;39m

[2m2021-01-27 11:37:36.187[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16692[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           
main][0;39m [36msim1.awakelab.sim1Application           [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting 
sim1Application on DESKTOP-MTELQ59 with PID 16692 
(C:\Users\Claudio\Documents\Programación\Simulacros\sim1\target\classes started by Claudio in 
C:\Users\Claudio\Documents\Programación\Simulacros\sim1)
[2m2021-01-27 11:37:36.189[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16692[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           
main][0;39m [36msim1.awakelab.sim1Application           [0;39m [2m:[0;39m No active profile set, 
falling back to default profiles: default
[2m2021-01-27 11:37:36.279[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m16692[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           
main][0;39m [36mo.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following 
location:


org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors
(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:99)

The following method did not exist:
```

'org.springframework.core.metrics.ApplicationStartup
org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory.getApplicationStartup()'

```
The method's class, org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory, is 
available from the following locations:

jar:file:/C:/Users/Claudio/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/5.2.8.RELEASE/spring- 
beans- 
5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/ConfigurableListableBeanFactory.class

The class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory: 
file:/C:/Users/Claudio/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/5.2.8.RELEASE/spring-beans- 
5.2.8.RELEASE.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of 
org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory
```

I don't know if i'm missing some config file or what, but i've already created the main class and method with the annotation SpringBootApplication and added the spring core dependency.

Comment: What is your spring version?

Comment: 2.3.2.RELEASE that is

Answer (score 0):

You have incompatible version of  `ConfigurableListableBeanFactory` method .

Try adding the following in your pom.xml (if the dependency does not exist)

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

If you have the dependency , check whether it is same as Spring version

**Edited**

Go to `C:/Users/Claudio/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context`  . Check if you have multiple versions of spring-context , like `5.2.8.RELEASE`  and other versions along with it. If you have too many versions, delete everything except the one with `2.3.2`  . Because it seems, other version files are being read instead of the actual one.

Comment: i have that dependence with that version

Comment: Are you using spring-cloud?

Comment: may be that i have two different versions references in pom? like the spring core is 5.3.1 and springframework version is 3.1.1.RELEASE?

Comment: i have different projects in here and maybe the others will fail if i erase those other versions

Comment: Try deleting other versions because we have to check if that is the possible cause of error . If it works , then we can go for any other counter-measure.

Comment: i delete everything and it seems to be downloading other versions but what i need